# Runtime detection of SSL support in the pg gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ssl

We have some Ruby code which does something like:

```
require 'pg'

# Create a remote Postgres database instance, and wait
# until it's online, then try to connect:
conn = PG::Connection.new(
    ... params ...
    sslmode: 'require')
```

The important part is that the remote Postgres instance is configured such that SSL usage is mandatory (e.g. [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8580/force-postgresql-clients-to-use-ssl)) -- the `sslmode: 'require'` in the client code is redundant.

This works fine on many developer machines, but some developers are noticing that they get some error like:

```
 FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

and the root cause seems to be that their `pg` gem does not actually have SSL support.

**My question: is there any way to determine if the `pg` gem does in fact have SSL support, without actually trying to connect to a server requiring SSL**? (It would be much better if we could detect the problem right away, instead of waiting until a remote Postgres instance has been created, and only then discovering the problem.)

My first thought was to check a method on the `pg` gem such as [init_openssl](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG.init_openssl), but the documentation claims:

> When SSL support is not compiled in, this function is present but does nothing.

and this behavior appears to be the same whether SSL support is present or not:

```
2.3.1 :002 > PG.init_openssl(true, true)
 => nil
```

Environment info: ruby 2.3 on recent OS X, `pg` gem 0.19.0, various versions of `libpq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure Ruby is compiled with OpenSSL support:

```
ruby -r rbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["configure_args"]'
'--prefix=/Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0-preview2' '' '--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared' 'build_alias=' 'host_alias=' 'target_alias=' 'CC=gcc'
```

Make sure `openssl` is somewhere in the `--with-opt-dir` output. Alternatively, you can check with this:

```
ruby -r openssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

Next, locate your `pg_ext.bundle`. The location of this will vary depending on how you install Ruby and gems, but if you're using RVM it's fairly straightforward to locate in `~/.rvm/gems`. For example, it is located here for me:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0-preview2/gems/pg-1.1.3/ext/pg_ext.bundle
```

Now run `otool -L` to find the libraries it is linked against:

```
otool -L /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0-preview2/gems/pg-1.1.3/ext/pg_ext.bundle
  /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0-preview2/gems/pg-1.1.3/ext/pg_ext.bundle:
  /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0-preview2/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.6.0)
  /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.11.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

Now run `otool -L` against the `libpq` dylib listed in the above output to see what it's linked against:

```
otool -L /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib:
  /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.11.0)
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

As long as it's linked against `libssl` and `libcrypto`, the installed `pg` gem should support OpenSSL as well.

Comment: Wow - it is really as difficult as I feared. Thanks a lot for this answer, I'll accept if nobody has a clever ruby-level solution.

Comment: The only Ruby-level option I found was [`PG::Connection.new.ssl_attribute()`](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/b6fd35539298a7f0307e71937a654d97fa44e6ba/ext/pg_connection.c#L3356-L3390) but this only functions on an established connection, and in your described scenario the connection cannot be established, ergo this method call would not work.